# Client cannot authenticate via: [TOKEN, KERBEROS)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, kerberos, distcp

From my spark application I am trying to `distcp` from hdfs to s3. My app does some processing on data and writes data to hdfs and that data I am trying to push to s3 via `distcp`. I am facing below error.  Any pointer will be helpful.

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation doAs - 
PriviledgedActionException as: (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.
Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: 
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
Client cannot authenticate via: [TOKEN, KERBEROS);
```

Comment: Maybe you need to call [kinit](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/user_commands/kinit.html) before starting to copy the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already  doing knit . Doing ugi.doAs new privilege action fixed this issue